# Sending ID from as3 to asp & geting sql result parameter at the SAME time?

Tags: database, actionscript-3, post

I can send a parameter from as3 to asp. And I can get a value from db. But unfortunatelly I cant combine both of them. Is it possible to send a ID parameter from as3 to asp where I want to make a sql query on a db. Then query result will return back to the as3. Users can login with their id number. And they can see their own datas on the as3 application. My sample codes are given:

**I can send values with these codes:**

```
var getParams:URLRequest = new URLRequest("http://www***********/data.asp");
getParams.method = URLRequestMethod.POST;
var paras:URLVariables = new URLVariables();
paras.parameter1 = ""+userID;
getParams.data = paras;
var loadPars:URLLoader = new URLLoader(getParams);
loadPars.addEventListener(Event.COMPLETE, loadCompleted);
loadPars.dataFormat = URLLoaderDataFormat.VARIABLES;
loadPars.load(getParams);
function loadCompleted(event:Event):void
{
     trace("sent")
}
```

I can get values from db with these codes:

```
var urlLoader:URLLoader =new URLLoader();
urlLoader.load(new URLRequest("http://www***********/data.asp"));
urlLoader.dataFormat = URLLoaderDataFormat.VARIABLES;
urlLoader.addEventListener(Event.COMPLETE, onXMLLoad);
function onXMLLoad(event:Event):void
{
var loader:URLLoader = URLLoader(event.target);
var scrptVars:URLVariables = new URLVariables(loader.data +"");

returnParameter= scrptVars.LINK0;
high.HighScore.text = returnParameter + "";
}
```

What is the logic of combining them?

Sory for my English level :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To combine the second one into the first, you just need to read the URLLoader's data property (which is the response from the server) on the `loadCompleted` method (same as you're doing in the `onXMLLoad` method):

```
function loadCompleted(event:Event):void
{
    trace("sent and received", loadPars.data);

    high.HighScore.text = loadPars.data.LINK0;
}
```

The COMPLETE event for a `URLLoader` fires once the request has received a response.  If your server adds data to that response, it can be found in the `data` property of the `URLLoader`.

So to summarize, sending and receiving can be done all in one operation with one URLLoader.  The data you *send* to the server, is found in the `URLRequest` object passed to the URLLoader, the data that *comes back* from that request, is found in the `data` property of the `URLLoader` object (but only after the COMPLETE event fires).

Comment: Thanks so much BadFeelingAboutThis.